# FCM custom sound in flutter iOS and Android

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Currently I am using

> firebase_messaging: ^6.0.1

for FCM notification. Already receiving notification but **without any sound** (android and iOS). Although I want custom sound for that and am aware of Notification channel in android (*how to play with notification channel in android with flutter*?) but currently no default sound even when shooting notification from server.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Device is not on silent or vibration mode right? if it is notification tray then set `sound: true`. also you can use [flutter_ringtone_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player) and can play sound on when push received on `onMessage`.

Comment: @RavinderKumar but  if app is in background or closed then it will not play

Answer (score 0):

You already have an instance of `fireBaseMessaging` if not create one :

```
FirebaseMessaging _fireBaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
```

and use below for iOS:

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _fireBaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
      _fireBaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
        print("Settings registered: $settings");
      });
}
```

and make sure you have added `FirebaseMessagingAutoInitEnabled = NO` in info.plist [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Comment: for iOS sound working? i am using `firebase_messaging: ^5.1.2`

Comment: no for iOS no sound even when sending from console but in android when sending  from console default sound works but not from server

Comment: check [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26005) in my device it's working.